# How to get all documents' IDs in a collection and store in a string array?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how to get all document IDs in a specific collection, and then I want to put them in a string array for further queries.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have any collection of `documents`, then array of id(s) would be

```
let docIDs = documents.map { $0.id }
```